# Passing input to an InputKey

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm following these instructions, trying to pass input to an `InputKey`: [Input-Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html#preapplying-input)

I got those definitions:

```
lazy val test = InputKey[Unit]("test")
lazy val test2 = InputKey[Unit]("test2")
```

and this code compiles:

```
test2 := {
  test.fullInput("aaa").evaluated
}
```

but this code

```
test2 := {
  val x = "aaa"
  test.fullInput(x).evaluated
}
```

fails to compile with the error

```
Illegal dynamic reference: x
test.fullInput(x).evaluated
               ^
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28371384/245024) I was able to make this workaround

```
test2 := {
  val x = "aaa"
  Def.inputTaskDyn[Unit]{ run.toTask(x)}
}.evaluated
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a [bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1095)
The reproduction case seems totaly the same as yours.